# dvb-s to dvb-c direct transmodulation

Tags: modulation, demodulation, qpsk

Is this possible to direct trans modulate DVB-S/S2 -> QI into -> DVB-C/C2 signals without doing it the way DVB-S/S2->Demodulator.ic-Transport Stream -> Modulator.ic-Transport Stream -> DVB-C/C2 ? Qpsk and Qam are similar, rf tuners the same, trouble within IQ. Direct conversion should be multichannel and cheaper within CATV systems.

Answer (score 1):

This should be impossible in most cases due to different modulation and coding schemes.

For example, DVB-S2 uses single carrier phase modulation wheras DVB-C2 uses OFDM modulation. There is no way to convert single carrier to OFDM without going to the digital domain.